Count repeating values in multiple time series
I have a quite simple problem. I have a dataset with multiple products, and the development of their prices over time. Now I need to identify periods in which the prices don't change over consecutive days (excluding weekends --> Friday and Monday are therefore consecutive).
Dataset:



ID
Date
Price




1
2024-02-01
1,00


1
2024-02-04
1,00


1
2024-02-05
1,20


1
2024-02-06
1,30


1
2024-02-07
1,30


2
2024-02-01
1,30


2
2024-02-04
0,90


2
2024-02-05
0,90


2
2024-02-06
0,90


2
2024-02-07
1,30



My output should look somewhat like this:



ID
start_date
end_date
price
repeated_days_count




1
2024-02-01
2024-02-04
1,00
2


1
2024-02-06
2024-02-07
1,30
2


2
2024-02-04
2024-02-06
0,90
3



As you can see, I need to avoid the following problems:

2024-02-01 until 2024-02-04: As above, this counts as consecutive days, i.e. ignore the weekend of 2024-02-02 and 2024-02-03)
If the same price appears another time in the series, it should not be counted. Only if it is on consecutive days.
If the same price (here 1,30) appears in the list right after each other, but not for the same ID, it should not be counted as consecutive --> shift().cumsum() would therefore not work here.

Any ideas? Maybe a shift().cumsum() but only within each ID?
So far I tried some variations of first shift().cumsum()
and then groupby().agg({"date": ["min", "max"], "price": "size"}
But none would solve the above mentioned problems together.

You can try:
def get_next_day(d):
    d += pd.Timedelta("1 day")

    if d.dayofweek == 4:
        d += pd.Timedelta("2 days")
    elif d.dayofweek == 5:
        d += pd.Timedelta("1 day")

    return d


def yield_group(g):
    if len(g) > 1:
        yield {
            "ID": g[0][0],
            "start_date": g[0][1],
            "end_date": g[-1][1],
            "price": g[0][2],
            "repeated_days_count": len(g),
        }


def generate_groups(ids, dates, prices):
    current_group = []
    prev_id = None
    prev_price = None
    expected_next_day = None

    for i, d, p in zip(ids, dates, prices):

        if prev_id is None:
            current_group.append((i, d, p))
        elif expected_next_day != d or prev_id != i or prev_price != p:
            yield from yield_group(current_group)
            current_group = [(i, d, p)]
        else:
            current_group.append((i, d, p))

        prev_id = i
        prev_price = p
        expected_next_day = get_next_day(d)

    yield from yield_group(current_group)


df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

out = pd.DataFrame(generate_groups(df["ID"], df["Date"], df["Price"]))
print(out)

Prints:
   ID start_date   end_date price  repeated_days_count
0   1 2024-02-01 2024-02-04  1,00                    2
1   1 2024-02-06 2024-02-07  1,30                    2
2   2 2024-02-04 2024-02-06  0,90                    3


try this:
def get_group_ids_and_start_mask(df: pd.DataFrame):
    combined_id_price = df[['ID', 'Price']].astype(str).pipe(
        lambda x: x['ID'].str.cat(x['Price'], sep='-')
    )
    new_group_start_mask = combined_id_price.ne(combined_id_price.shift())
    continuous_group_ids = new_group_start_mask.cumsum()
    return continuous_group_ids, new_group_start_mask


group_ids, group_start_mask = get_group_ids_and_start_mask(df)

m = group_ids.groupby(group_ids).transform('count').ge(2)
stable_price_records = df.loc[m]

group_ids, group_start_mask = get_group_ids_and_start_mask(
    stable_price_records)
groupby_aggregations = {
    'ID': ('ID', 'first'),
    'Start': ('Date', 'first'),
    'End': ('Date', 'last'),
    'Count': ('Price', 'count')
}
price_stability_summary = stable_price_records.groupby(
    group_ids, as_index=False).agg(**groupby_aggregations)
print(price_stability_summary)
>>>
   ID       Start         End  Count
0   1  2024-02-01  2024-02-04      2
1   1  2024-02-06  2024-02-07      2
2   2  2024-02-04  2024-02-06      3

